# Alfresco Share - Importing existing HTML page with links and images

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

We are using Alfresco Share to manage documents. On one of our sites, we would like to make available a report created by an outside organization that consists in 3 web pages with many images. This report will be replaced every couple of months.

Is there any simple way to upload this report into an Alfresco site without having to edit links and sources for the images?

As with other documents, theses HTML documents and images should only be available to specific Alfresco groups.

Answer (score 2):

If you create the report in for example Webdav or Cifs and you use the refences to the images in your report.

Then users can still use those locations and see the images.

It's also quite easy to write a custom script which searches in the content of the html file and replaces the href values by alfresco noderefs.

For example your report is in the root folder report.html and the images are all in images/.
Then just use the image name and loop through the alfresco folder and get the noderef.

Second option is to store the images on a fileserver or website and use those links in the report. The use `view in browser` on the document and all the images will load.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will try these solutions and give an update.